# nodes_modules folder is missing in Autodesk example

Tags: autodesk-forge

my project shows a "nodes_modules" folder and the Autodesk example does not show this folder.

also, my authentication is not working.

Comment: Which node.js example are you using? Commonly, the `nodes_modules` folder should appear after executing `npm install` in the folder where the `package.js` placed.

Answer (score 0):

Which node.js example are you using? Commonly, the `nodes_modules` folder should appear after executing npm install in the folder where the `package.js` placed. So, could you share more details about this issue? Thanks!